# Use multiple scopes with the Office 365 API

Tags: office365, office365api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-api, office365-restapi

I want to use the two scopes `https://outlook.office.com/Mail.Read` and `https://outlook.office.com/calendars.read` to read an authenticated users' email and calendar. I followed the [official .Net (WPF) tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-wpf/) to authenticate the user and obtain a token. It works well as long as my scope is only one of the ones above. As soon as I use both, I don't get back a token when I try to obtain it.

That's basically what I do:

```cs
private static string[] scopes = { "https://outlook.office.com/Mail.Read", "https://outlook.office.com/calendars.read" };

// sign-in/authenticate logic (with PromptBehavior.Always/Never) from tutorial

// here, the result doesn't contain a token:
result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(scopes, null, clientId, redirectUri, new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always, null));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `Mail.Read` scope to all lower-case:

```
private static string[] scopes = { "https://outlook.office.com/mail.read", "https://outlook.office.com/calendars.read" };
```

It looks like a bug in the ADAL library. I filed an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/275).

Comment: Thank you very much for this comment. This fixed my problem. I also tried it with lowercase letters once, but most likely I had something else going on then which caused another issue... By the way, in the Outlook Mail REST API reference all the scopes are written with upper-case (and with http instead of https)...